# How to make svg scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Hello all I am working on javascript jquery and svg.I want to ask a question that is it possible to make my svg:g element scrollable.
Like I have one div containing an svg element and that svg intern contains many svg:g elements
I want to make one of my g scrollable.
I have read about 
[scroll.js](http://www.carto.net/svg/gui/scrollbar/) but i can not use it so is there any other library in jqquery or javascript which provides scrolling support in svg

or any other wany to do it like make a dive inside svg etc

Any help will be appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://polymaps.org/

or this: http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/mapbox/